# Why does the "infeasible" Waugh-Frisch-Lovell estimator agree with the usual one?

Tags: regression, asymptotics

In Lemma 1 of [these lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/14-382-econometrics-spring-2017/resources/mit14_382s17_lec1/), Chernozhukov and Fernández-Val write that partialing out with the Frisch-Waugh-Lovell theorem has an "adaptivity" property. Namely, suppose we regress $Y$ on $D$ and $W$ and partial out $W$.

The Frisch-Waugh-Lovell theorem tells us the coefficients on $D$ are equivalent to the ones we get by regressing $\check Y$ on $\check D$, where $\check Y$ is the residual from regressing $Y$ on $W$. Call this coefficient $\hat\beta.$

Chernozhukov and Fernández-Val point out we can also run an infeasible regression by regressing $\tilde Y$ on $\tilde D$, where $\tilde Y$ is the residual from subtracting from the observed values of $Y$ the *population-level* projection of $Y$ on to $W$. Call this coefficient $\tilde\beta.$

They claim that under certain regularity conditions, we have
$\sqrt{n}(\hat\beta - \tilde\beta) \to_p 0.$

I'm interested in the (easier) case where the number of covariates is constant in $n$, but I have not been able to find a proof of this claim in any of their references. (They describe the proof as "simple" in this case, so I suspect I'm just missing something basic.)

Any resources or hints for the proof would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Update: I figured it out! Posting as an answer in case anyone else has this question. This is just an application of orthogonality properties of OLS.

For simplicity, assume $D$ consists of a single variable and $W$ contains a constant term.

Let $\hat\gamma$ be the vector of coefficients from regressing $D$ on $W$, and let $\hat\delta$ be the vector of coefficients from regressing $Y$ on $W$, and let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ be the sample inner product $\langle E,F \rangle = \dfrac{1}{n} \sum E_iF_i$.

We then have
$$\hat{\beta} = \dfrac{\langle D - \hat \gamma W, Y - \hat \delta W \rangle   }{|| D - \hat \gamma W ||^2 }$$
and
$$\tilde{\beta} = \dfrac{\langle D - \tilde\gamma W, Y - \tilde\delta W \rangle   }{|| D - \tilde\gamma W ||^2 }$$
By the orthogonality properties of OLS, we have

$$|| D - \tilde \gamma W||^2  = || D - \hat \gamma W||^2  + ||(\tilde \gamma  - \hat \gamma)W||^2$$

and
$$\langle D - \tilde \gamma W, Y - \tilde \delta W \rangle  = \langle D - \hat \gamma W, Y - \hat \delta W \rangle + \langle (\hat\gamma - \tilde\gamma)W, (\hat\delta - \tilde\delta)W \rangle$$
So
$$\hat\beta - \tilde\beta = \dfrac{\langle D - \hat \gamma W, Y - \hat \delta W \rangle||(\tilde \gamma  - \hat \gamma)W||^2 - || D - \tilde \gamma W||^2 \langle (\hat\gamma - \tilde\gamma)W, (\hat\delta - \tilde\delta)W \rangle}{\left( ||D - \tilde \gamma W||^2  + ||(\tilde \gamma  - \hat \gamma)W||^2\right) ||D - \tilde \gamma W||^2} $$
But $\langle D - \hat \gamma W, Y - \hat \delta W \rangle$ converges in probability to the covariance of $\tilde D$ and $\tilde Y$, and $|| D - \tilde \gamma W||^2$ converges in probability to the variance of $D,$ so the result follows because $|| (\hat \gamma - \tilde \gamma)W||$ and $||(\hat \delta - \tilde \delta) W||$ are both $O(n^{-1/2}).$